# Does anybody know why this is not letting my form submit? jQuery Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to allow the user to search for a movie using Rotten Tomatoes API but no matter what I attempt I seem to be having loads of trouble. I'm new to jquery and keep getting an error 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' the second line of the jQuery code. Does anyone know a solution?

Here is the code..

HTML Form

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="GET"><h3>Search for a movie here:</h3><br> 
<input type="text" id="inputbox" value="">&nbsp;
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!">
```

jQuery & Ajax

```
 $(function(){

    $('form[name="myform"]').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#films table').empty(); //removes previous search results before adding the new ones.

        var apikey = "MY API KEY";
        var baseUrl = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0";
        var moviesSearchUrl = baseUrl + '/movies.json?apikey=' + apikey;
        var query = $('#inputbox').val(); //uses the value from the input box as the query search

        // sends the query
        $.ajax({
            url: moviesSearchUrl + '&q=' + encodeURI(query),
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: searchCallback // if successful, run searchCallback function
        });

        // receives the results
        function searchCallback(data) {
            $('#films table').append('Found ' + data.total + ' results for ' + query);
            var movies = data.movies;
            $.each(movies, function(index, movie) {
                $('#films table').append('<tr><td width="70" rowspan="2"><a href="' + movie.links.alternate +
                '" title="Click here to view film information for ' + movie.title + '."><img class="ajaximage" src="'
                + movie.posters.thumbnail + '" /></a></td><td class="ajaxfilmlisttitle"><h3><a href="' + movie.links.alternate +
                '" title="Click here to view film information for ' + movie.title + '.">' + movie.title + '</a></h3>Release year: '
                + movie.year + '</td></tr><tr><td class="ajaxfilmlistinfo">Audience Score: ' + movie.ratings.audience_score +
                '%<br>' + 'Cinema Release Date: ' + movie.release_dates.theater +
                '<br>Runtime: ' + movie.runtime + ' minutes</td></tr>');
            });
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you importing jquery into the page? If so, what version?

Comment: Yes I'm importing <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: That's an old version of the library that doesn't support `.on()`. Import the newest version you can (1.11.1 I think currently).

Comment: Well now I just feel stupid. That fixed my error but for some reason the data is still not being displayed on the page

Comment: Hmm well I've not used that API; maybe you're getting an error? Check the developer console - that should give you HTTP request status etc

Comment: I got it working man I used console.log(movies( to make sure the data was being retrieved successfully and then $(document.body).append to display it. Thank you so much for your help!